# Laravel query with joins, same name in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a large query.  For all intents and purposes, I'll recreate the issue using a smaller query as an example:

```
DB::table('cases')
    ->join('contacts', 'cases.id', '=', 'contacts.id')
    ->select('cases.name', 'contacts.name')
    ->get();
```

And then in laravel's templating (Blade) when I do a foreach loop and print the results, it's printing the results from the cases table for `{{ $case->name }}`

I understand the problem and why it is happening, but how can I make it work properly?

Comment: 1) You can't. This is a PDO restriction and has nothing to do with laravel. If you need them both, you'll have to alias it in your query: `select('case.name as case_name ...')`. 2) **intents and purposes** not **intensive purposes**.

Comment: That's what I thought.. How could I do this in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a PDO restriction and has nothing to do with laravel. If you need them both, you'll have to alias it in your query:

```php
DB::table('cases')
    ->join('contacts', 'cases.id', '=', 'contacts.id')
    ->selectRaw('cases.name as cases_name, contacts.name as contacts_name')
    ->get();
```